# Is "Total Energy = Kinetic + Potential" always true in a harmonic oscillator?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, harmonic-oscillator

Consider a object executing simple harmonic motion in one dimensions due to a variable external force (like a spring maybe).
I like to think that at any point in it's motion at any time the mechanical energy of the entire system remains conserved. That is, the sum of the kinetic energy of the object and the potential energy stored in the spring(or something else) remains the same constant value throughout it's motion.

But I recently got acquainted to the following question that made me doubt my concepts. I've tried to generalize the question so that it follows the homework policy on this site.

> A linear harmonic oscillator of force constant $K$ and amplitude $A$ has a total mechanical energy of $J$ joules. Find the maximum kinetic energy and the maximum potential energy.
>   (Assume $J > \frac 12 KA^2)$

At the extreme position of the object, the potential energy is maximum and kinetic energy is zero. Since the potential energy stored is given by $\frac 12 Kx^2$ (x is displacement from mean), I would expect it to equal $\frac 12 KA^2$ at the extrema with no kinetic energy. **Why isn't the total mechanical energy $J$ equal to $\frac 12 KA^2$?** (Since Total= Kinetic(0) + Potential($\frac 12 KA^2$))
The kinetic energy must be maximum at the mean position and equal to the total mechanical energy $J$ and also equal to $\frac 12 KA^2$ .

I indeed did a little research and found a similar question [somewhere else](https://www.askiitians.com/forums/Mechanics/a-linear-harmonic-oscillator-of-force-constant-2x1_141194.htm) and [here](https://www.meritnation.com/ask-answer/question/a-linear-harmonic-oscillator-of-force-constant-2-106n-m-and/physics/9890866), but that doesn't explain my point above. The first link just assumes that $J$ = Maximum potential energy but not equal to $\frac 12 KA^2$ and doesn't explain anything in detail. The second link provides a different answer where $\frac 12 KA^2$ = Maximum potential energy but not equal to $J$.

Comment: "Consider a object executing simple harmonic motion in one dimensions due to a variable external force (like a spring maybe)." - The energy of a harmonic oscillator (even one with no damping) won't in general be conserved if you're coupling in energy to it with a "variable external force".

Comment: If this is just a harmonic oscillator, the total energy should indeed be $k A^2 / 2$. There might be a mistake in the question; you should post the details (though sadly this may make the question off topic).

Comment: @SamuelWeir But I've read everywhere that the total energy remains constant even if a spring is attached.

Comment: @Javier The question was asked in a national highly competitive examination and I highly doubt it might be a mistake.

Comment: And yet the question as asked does not make sense, so either there is a mistake or we're missing something.

Comment: The question makes sense if the center of mass of the system is moving. Then, even at the maximum extension, there will still be some kinetic energy from the motion of the center of mass. This means the maximum potential energy is $\frac{1}{2}KA^2$ and the maximum kinetic energy is $J$ (with the _minimum_ kinetic energy being $J-\frac{1}{2}KA^2$).

Comment: @JadenYuki "But I've read everywhere that the total energy remains constant even if a spring is attached." - No, what you have in this case is a "forced harmonic oscillator", and energy isn't constant. A forced harmonic oscillator is analogous to a driven LC oscillator. During part of the cycle the oscillator may absorb energy while at another part of the cycle the oscillator may release energy, so energy doesn't stay constant. The time-averaged energy over an entire cycle or over long time periods will in general be constant, though.

Comment: I'm going with @SamuelWeir    
There is an external force acting on the oscillator and therefore the energy is "lost".

Comment: It's important to note here that the actual question that the OP was asked did not mention a driven harmonic oscillator at all. As such, it's possible that the question was referring to a free harmonic oscillator (whose center of mass may be moving).

Comment: I'm with @probably_someone. this explanation can uphold the concepts of the OP and provide justification to the question.

Comment: That sounds like a badly written question -- are you sure you're quoting _exactly_ what it said?

Comment: @knzhou well I did generalize it. The actual question had numerical data.

Comment: @JadenYuki But did you generalize it correctly? In the most straightforward reading of the question, it's simply wrong. There _could_ be other stuff that hasn't been mentioned (gravity, a time-dependent driving force, friction, a time-varying mass, etc.) but we don't know what it is from the question.

Comment: @knzhou I'm pretty sure nothing else was provided.

Comment: Then the question is either wrong or very badly written!

Comment: Not to insult the exam or anything. I help write a competitive national exam too -- the most competitive one in the United States. We still have typos. It happens.

Answer (score 0):

A way of analysing a vertical spring-mass system is shown in the diagram below where $A$ is the amplitude of motion of the mass $m$.

[image]

With the mass in position $\mathbf 1$ assume that the spring potential energy (spe), the gravitational potential energy of the mass (gpe) and the kinetic energy of the mass (ke) are all zero.
So the total mechanical energy of the spring-mass system is zero.

At position $\mathbf2$ which is the static equilibrium position where the net force on the mass is zero with $mg-KA=0$

$\rm{gpe} = - mgA = -KA^2$, $\rm{spe} = \frac 12 KA^2$, $\rm{ke} = \frac 12KA^2$ with the total mechanical energy still zero.

At position $\mathbf 3$

$\rm{gpe} = - 2mgA = -2KA^2$, $\rm{spe} = 2KA^2$, $\rm{ke} = 0$ with the total mechanical energy still zero.

Since the question states that the total mechanical energy is $J$ all one needs to do is to change the zero of the gpe so that the gpe at position $\mathbf 1$ is $J$.

Thus at position $\mathbf 2$, $\rm{gpe} = -KA^2 +J$ and at position $\mathbf 3$, $\rm{gpe} = -2KA^2 +J$.

Comment: Position $\mathbf{2}$ in not of static equilibrium but dynamic equilibrium as the block has velocity (and obviously net force zero).

Answer (score 0):

The system may have more energy than just Kinetic and Elastic Potential energy. It may have Gravitational potential energy (the experiment is done at some height,or I can just arbitrarily assign 0 GPE at some depth).

Remember, there's no way of knowing the total energy of a system. All we can measure is change in energy. In the case of harmonic oscillator, all we can say is that Kinetic energy in converted into Elastic potential energy and vice versa, thus the total energy is constant. Energy associated with oscillation may not be same as total energy.

Answer (score 0):

In SHM we know that the energy oscillates between kinetic and potential energy forms, keeping the total mechanical energy constant. For example in horizontal spring mass system at maximum displacement position, kinetic energy is zero, potential energy is maximum and its value is equal to the total mechanical energy. Similarly at mean position the potential energy is zero,the kinetic energy is maximum and its value is equal to the total mechanical energy. In this case conversion of total energy is taking place between kinetic and potential forms. However this is not the situation always. Not always the total mechanical energy is oscillating between kinetic and potential forms but a part of the total mechanical energy may always remain as potential energy(or kinetic energy) and remaining energy  oscillates between kinetic and potential forms. Following is an example where a part of total mechanical energy always remains in potential form, it is present there at the point of maximum velocity i.e. maximum KE also. So in the present problem we have to determine the maximum kinetic energy of the system only. [image]

Comment: Questions or Answers with images of math, instead of using $\text{math formatting}$ on the site are frowned upon. Good work though.

Comment: You can start learning mathjax from this post: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020